# How do I get a Springer book which reference proofs for time series linear and non-linear regression?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references

I am sure people know Springer has a lot of math/stat books some of which proofs. Was wondering if people know which books have proofs on the following. I have browsed through a lot of them in the library but could not find enough info for them.

```
Time series
Linear regression
Non-linear regression
```

Was wondering if someone could make some recommendations ?

This is a cross-post but I got no reply there:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177104/how-do-i-get-a-springer-book-reference-of-proofs-for-time-series-linear-non-linear-models.

Comment: I would suggest Ron Gallant's 1987 *Nonlinear Statistical Models*.

Comment: Why just Springer? As @DJohnson's comment implies, excellent books published on statistics by Wiley, CRC Press, Cambridge UP,  Oxford UP, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The Time Series book by Peter Brockwell and Richard A. Davis and it is published by Springer-Verlag. It was published in its second edition in 1991.